# Is there a way I can add GFWL files or downgrade Arkham Asylum to the Steam version that had GFWL achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, xbox-network, batman-arkham-asylum, games-for-windows-live

I recently bought Arkham Asylum on Steam, and I am too obsessed with Xbox achievements. Unfortunately the current version(s) have been patched to remove GFWL, which I totally understand, but I seem to be a masochist and want it re-added. Outside of buying the Windows/Disc version, are there any ways to import the files and modify how it boots, or download older versions of the game through Steam?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it would apply to this particular game, but you could check the "Betas" tab under the game's properties to see if they offer older versions there.  Some games do (mostly 4Xs, in my experience) but I'm not sure about the Arkham series.